# USB-C video (xiaomi laptop to Dell display, no signal)

Tags: display, monitor, displayport, usb-c

I can't make the USB-C video work between a Xiaomi Mi Notebook with Intel 7th Gen and a Dell U2715H.
I'm running on Ubuntu 17.10 up to date, kernel 4.13.0-38-generic

It "almost" works :)
Both the display gnome applet (see screenshot) and xrandr see the display connected. 
I've [this cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0744GWJ8X/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that goes from the USB-C port in the laptop (the one also used for charging) to the DP IN port on the Dell monitor.
I've enabled DisplayPort 1.2 on the monitor.

xrandr output:

> DP-1 connected 2560x1440+3968+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
>      2560x1440     59.95*+
>      2048x1152     60.00
>      1920x1200     59.88
>      1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98

[...]

> HDMI-2 connected 2048x1152+1920+288 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
>      2048x1152     60.00*

Still, when I switch the Monitor to use DP input instead of HDMI, there is no signal. 
Also, the USB-C cable is supposed to charge the laptop but as well, this does not happen.

Maybe someone can help. Thanks :)

[image: See the built-in laptop display, the HDMI version of the Dell that goes up to 2048 max and the larger DP version of the Dell which goes up to 2560]